# Syncing Firefox and Google Chrome Browser Bookmarks

Tags: chrome, firefox, bookmark

I am looking for good solutions for syncing Google Chrome and Firefox Bookmarks.

I currently use XMarks, but sometimes it is "stuck".  A solution which lets me recover without losing data would be OK.

I have seen Google Bookmarks indicated as a solution, but the plugins I have seen are quite old.

Comment: Similar question, with more demands: [Bookmark sync tool between Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera browsers?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3317/2437)

Comment: So do you want to sync just the bookmarks, or also passwords and possibly other things?

Comment: About "similar questions" - the solution was XMarks, which I have problems with.

Comment: @niduc Only Bookmarks.

Comment: There were also two other suggestions, which did not get described in further detail (in the same answer)

Comment: I assumed those were to old.  Will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Found this one recently, it is working delightfully for me between Firefox, Chrome, Microsoft Edge, and Vivaldi, Linux and Windows:

https://xbrowsersync.org

Sorry, should have put this in originally: I have zero affiliation with this product.

Comment: Hi Jeb.  The system has flagged your answers because you just left 3 identical answers all recommending the same product.  Please disclose to our community if you happen to have any affiliation with this product.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now that Xmarks is gone, I've been using with [Floccus Bookmark Sync](https://floccus.org/). It has extensions for Firefox and Chromium browsers, Android and iPhone apps and can sync using Google Drive, any NextCloud server, or any Webdav server.