# Secure bookmark sync, "secure xmarks"?

Tags: windows, firefox, file-synchronization, bookmark

I'd like to use a bookmark manager, but I'd like my data to stay my own.  I happened to read about [Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com/) ToS/use or what-have-you before checking out this site for recommendations, but I'm glad to see that people [are pointing out](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/bookmark-sync-tool-between-internet-explorer-firefox-chrome-safari-and-opera) that Xmarks will look through and aggregate your data (and other stuff).  In effect, I'd like Xmarks to take the model of [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/), their parent company, with my data.  Then I would send them my money.

I primarily use Firefox on Windows, but I also use [Palemoon](https://www.palemoon.org/), Firefox on Android, and I'm experimenting with a few other Firefox forks and Linux.

Must have features

- Firefox support
- Bookmark management (CRUD)
- Synchronization and/or backup
- Pre-Internet encryption of data
- Folder sorting
- Tagging
- Windows Support

Features I'd like to have

- Cross browser support (ie Palemoon)
- Mobile (Android) support
- Free or low cost
- Local database I can manage
- Secure connection to the cloud

I came across [Linkman](http://www.outertech.com/en/bookmark-manager), which has almost all of the features I am looking for, but I'm not so sure about the synchronization options.  I think [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/) would probably be the way to go, but I am hoping there's a software that does it all together.

Firefox Sync's ToS seem to be good:

> Encrypted User Data
>
> The Firefox Sync Service encrypts User Data on your computer and
>   uploads encrypted User Data over the network using SSL communication.
>   We believe that user privacy is important, and we require that the
>   User Data is encrypted to reside on Mozilla’s Firefox Sync Service
>   servers. Those items you choose to synchronize across devices using
>   Firefox Sync are examples of User Data that is designed to be
>   encrypted before leaving your computer. These can include your
>   browsing history, form history, bookmarks, saved passwords,
>   preferences, and open tabs.

However, I don't like the direction that Firefox is headed.  They are trying to be Google Chrome in look and function, so I've started experimenting with other browsers.  Thankfully, many alternative browsers are forks of Firefox.  The most promising is Palemoon, and many extensions seem to work fine in it or have a fork from Palemoon.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Turtl](https://turtlapp.com/). It is free, open source and client side encrypted. It is cross platform. It has both Firefox and Chrome extensions. Overall it is amazing.